# how to connect the Raspberrypi to internet with Sim7020E using 1NCE IoT FLAT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gsm, sim-card

hello I work with an Rpi 4 and an Rpi Zero W and I want to activate the internet connection by a communication network using SIM7020E. I manage to establish the contact by checking the basic commands on Minicom but the connection is not activated. I must provide at the end transfer data from my Rpi by Email but without Wifi or Ethernet Cable.
i program with python
please can someone help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions and answers, but making an internet connection is not programming topic.

Comment: It may be relevant to post your question in the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the 1NCE Developer Hub.
In the recipes section are examples of using the SIM7000G, which works very much in the same way and can be compared. You find all the recipes here: https://help.1nce.com/dev-hub/recipes and look for SIM7000G.

The main things you need to do is to configure the SIM7020E via the serial interface and send the correct commands from your python application.

1. Do the overall network registration of the module as shown here: https://help.1nce.com/dev-hub/recipes/sim7000g-network-registration
2. From there, you can already start sending data. Unfortunately, there is not a direct example for sending mail but as I expect you are using some mail delivery service that also has an API, you can follow the following guide for that: https://help.1nce.com/dev-hub/recipes/sim7000g-http-post

It will show you what commands are required for an HTTP POST call.